# can't create volume on disk-based libvirt storage pool

Tags: centos, redhat, kvm-virtualization, virsh

I followed Red Hat's doc (to the letter) on adding a disk-based storage pool for my libvirt/kvm server. Here's what I see:

```
[root@kvm ~]# virsh pool-info guest_image_disk
Name:           guest_image_disk
UUID:           5d30a266-2d80-43a8-b6bd-b682eb19a043
State:          running
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      yes
Capacity:       232.89 GiB
Allocation:     0.00 B
Available:      232.89 GiB
```

The doc didn't say anything about setting up a partition on the disk; it only says the disk needs a gpt label so I made sure it had one.

The Red Hat page shows this as the xml example file:

```
<pool type='disk'>
  <name>guest_images_disk</name>
  <source>
    <device path='/dev/sdb'/>
    <format type='gpt'/>
  </source>
  <target>
    <path>/dev</path>
  </target>
</pool>
```

The confusing part is the path. On my Ubuntu libvirt/kvm machine I used a directory-based volume, so it's a pathname:

```
<path>/store0/libvirt/pools/default</path>
```

There is no (or I can't find any) [Creating a disk based storage pool using virsh](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/chap-Virtualization_Administration_Guide-Storage_Pools-Storage_Pools.html#idp17463152) for Red Hat 7 so perhaps that's the problem. I'm running CentOS 7.
If I use /var/lib/libvirt/images/sdb as the path, virsh pool-define is happy with that but I'm left wondering whether the pool disk is mounted there. Is that  a mount point or no?

Comment: virsh vol-create-as default vol0 232G resulted in this:
`[root@kvm ~]# virsh pool-info default
Name:           default
UUID:           13df371e-8bc1-49c1-ad54-596cdbd15190
State:          running
Persistent:     yes
Autostart:      no
Capacity:       232.89 GiB
Allocation:     464.00 GiB
Available:      16777215.77 TiB`

Comment: Your pool looks fine. What is the problem you are having?

Comment: I can't see where it's attached/imported/mounted in the file system. Did you notice I have 16777215.77 TiB available in my comment? That's impossible.

Comment: Again, my problem with the document is this. In the example .xml  the <target><path> variable has "/dev" in it. I just added a disk to my Ubuntu machine using virt-manager and it required me to use a fs pathname.

Comment: What does the Ubuntu setup have to do with anything?

Comment: Nothing.
I was expecting to see additional space appear somewhere on the existing filesystem.

Comment: So if I set up a default pool on /dev/sdb and use "/dev" for the path, virsh sets up a partition on /dev/sdb. What is the pathname I should use for that space? Anyone?